# What have we [deleted]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, synonym-request, clean-up

The [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleted) tag has a total of 117 posts (a new post every ~6 days), of that: 59% have a score of 0 or less, 9% are closed, there are only 3 followers and the tag's excerpt and wiki are both empty.

To me, [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleted) seems like a past tense version of [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete). What does [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleted) have to offer us that [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete) can't?

Would some sort of clean up, synonym or even a burnination be in order here (for either tag)?

<sup>As jordanhill123 [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262044/what-have-we-deleted#comment50558_262044), whatever we end up doing, the [deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deletion) tag could also join [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleted).</sup>

Comment: 20 minutes and no activity. Looks like Meta is in shock !! ;-)

Comment: What about [deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deletion)? Should it be in the same category and in consideration for cleanup too?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're suggesting [tag:deleted] be made into a synonym for [tag:delete]. The question is whether [tag:delete] would be considered valid, although it looks you think [tag:delete] should **not** be deleted. ;) (I would tend to agree with the latter point.)

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible to remove it, since the tag is already [tag:deleted]!

Comment: [`delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/delete) is a C++ keyword which can probably refer to quite a wide range of questions about deleted methods, their semantics etc. So I believe it would be a valid tag. However in this case the wiki summary should be edited to include this meaning.

Comment: This post needs to be tagged [tag:recursion]

Comment: @Bakuriu `delete` is a keyword in PHP, too, and several other languages. However, can anyone be an expert in `delete`? If you removed all the other tags, would it make sense on its own? I don't think your metric for tag validity is correct.

Comment: These tags [can be burinated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268202/2982225) as the post has been open for long and no one has made any opposition. Enjoy your weekend deleting "deleted" :)

Comment: Just for context: it's usually included along with [tag:undo], [tag:recover], [tag:restore], or something of that nature.

Comment: Is [tag:soft-delete] still relevant? I would think so.

Comment: @metacubed Yes it is.

Comment: This should be a [baleet](http://www.hrwiki.org/wiki/50_emails) request, not a burninate request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### <s>Burnination in progress...</s> Update: [burnination completed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298476/3488231)

- [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleted) completed at 11:30 on 10<sup>th</sup> August 2014(thanks to [Unihedron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622940/unihedron), [FunctionR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234422/functionr) & [metacubed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2702368/metacubed)).
- [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete)    [completed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298476/3488231)
- [deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deletion) completed at 20:00 on 29<sup>th</sup> August 2015.
- [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleting) completed at 23:00 on 29<sup>th</sup> August 2015.

If you would like to help participate, please remember to fix *all* outstanding issues with the question, such as,

- Re-tagging with appropriate tags (in this case, [delete-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete-operator), [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management), [sql-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-delete), etc.),
- fix typos/grammar/format,
- remove noise (such as, "thanks", "I'm a newbie", etc.).

Comment: Could we add [[tag:deletion]] to the burniate queue?

Comment: @Chris Sure, I don't see any reason why not.

Comment: As the remaining three tags are still here after a year (and this post is tagged [status-completed]), I've posted [a separate burninate request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298476/3488231) specifically for them.

Answer (score 2):

Neither [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete) nor [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleted) make any sense, they should both get removed since they are too vague and too broad.

There are so many operations, language features, OS commands and other unrelated things that could sort under those tags. As we can tell by taking a brief look at some posts tagged with these tags.