# Let's [erase] this tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[erase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erase) should be dropped as the questions that mention it have nothing in common.

Comment: Why not merge it into [tag:delete]? Do you want to remove that tag as well? It should be disambiguated then, not removed: this tag carries meaning.

Comment: Hard to imagine how either tag could be even remotely useful.

Comment: @Gilles http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262044/what-have-we-deleted

Comment: How about `[erase] [deletion]`, and adding the tag dropped in the other meta-question?

Answer (score 1):

The tag [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete) is being burninated at the moment and will be gone eventually, so merging with it would not make sense.

(See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270352/4370109 and [Should we [delete] [deletion] and [deleting]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298476/should-we-delete-deletion-and-deleting) )

The [erase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erase) does seem to be used in those questions where someone wants to discuss actually doing a data wipe (rather than a file system delete) based on the description:

> This tag refers to the process of removing or deleting data, text, files, or memory.

There are 405 postings tagged under erase.