# Should we [delete] [deletion] and [deleting]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262044/3488231) meta post from last year was about burninating [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleted). During the discussion, there seems to be consensus that [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete), [deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deletion) and [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleting) should also be burninated as they are too broad and ambiguous and usually do not add anything meaningful to the question.

As a result of that post, [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleted) was burninated, but according to the accepted answer the other three tags are "still cleaning up".

The tag wikis for [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete) and [deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deletion) both states that the tags should not be used.

As of now, [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete) has 6.6k questions, [deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deletion) has 159, and [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleting) has 143.

The amount of [deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deletion) and [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleting) is quite small. Let's put in some effort to get these two removed, then proceed to [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete), shall we?

Comment: Let us [delete] [deletion] and [deleting]

Comment: This question [Oracle - deletion based on date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230322/deletion-based-on-date-of-insertion-of-entry-into-table-in-oracle) might fall short if [tag:deletion] is removed

Comment: @MicroVirus I'm not familiar with Oracle, but wouldn't [tag:sql-delete] suffice?

Comment: Neither am I, but I think so? I'm somewhat reluctant to do this myself, because I am not an expert.

Comment: @MicroVirus and OP: I'm not that much of an Oracle expert either, but the tag is completely superflous in the question and should simply be removed. The actual question in that case is "does oracle have an implicit creation timestamp for rows" or rather, "how can I find rows based on the date when they were inserted"; the specific action OP wants to do isn't of any importance (e.g. you wouldn't have a separate question tagged with "update" or "select" if OP wanted to do an SQL update or select instead of a delete).

Comment: This was already done before and accomplished nothing but [creating a mess](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293773/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant But if the [delete] tag is completely removed from the system, it cannot be used unless a user with > 1.5k rep creates it again. And I doubt such an ambiguous and superfluous tag will be created by a relatively high-rep user.

Comment: Well, I would create it, given how completely useless [sql-delete] turned out to be.

Comment: @HansPassant then don't use either [sql-delete] nor [delete]. The task here is inconsequential. You can replace it with update, create, select, etc., yet that doesn't mean you need to tag a question for each verb of the english vocabulary it contains. Or you want questions tagged with [sql][delete][rows]?

Comment: Question: What tag is appropriate to use for programmatically destroying C++ objects?

Comment: @chrylis The [c++] tag. Quoting from Chris Baker's [comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262044/what-have-we-deleted#comment51137_262044) in the linked post, "`delete` is a keyword in PHP, too, and several other languages. However, can anyone be an expert in `delete`? If you removed all the other tags, would it make sense on its own?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Status of Tag Removal

- [deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deletion) <strike>159</strike> Completed
- [deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleting) <strike>143</strike> Completed
- [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete) <strike>6600</strike> <strike>7200</strike> <strike>144</strike> Completed

Some other related tags:

- [deletable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deletable) <strike>3</strike> Completed

## Remaining Work

There are some closed, locked and protected questions with the [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete) tag:

- **Locked**: <strike>2</strike> [0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelete%5D+locked%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+)
- **Closed**: <strike>142</strike> [0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelete%5D+locked%3Ano+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ayes)
- **New**: [0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelete%5D+locked%3Ano+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano)

The closed questions, on editing, get bumped into the re-open queue, so perhaps those with >3k might want to do it. I can easily bump them all up, but restrained myself.

The locked questions will need moderator action before the tag can be burninated.

*The [delete] tag has now been deleted!*

Comment: Please stop spamming the home page with tag-edits on closed crap questions that need to be deleted. Leave them alone for users with delete-vote privileges to handle (which doesn't bump them to the home page). Worse, once you remove the tag it becomes that much harder to find the crap questions that need to be deleted.

Comment: Are you just tag editing all the questions, good, bad, otherwise?

Comment: @durron597 - No. I've not done much editing of these recently as the closed ones are being dealt with by others. When I was editing  I flagged appropriately and did full edits as recommended, and tried to do it slow enough not to bump up too many at a time (over two months).

Comment: I brought up this request in the SO Close Vote Reviewers chatroom. There are currently no more questions tagged [delete] and the tag will be removed overnight. Once again, I would like to thank everyone who helped out.