# Should we del [del]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

There's around 100 questions tagged [del](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/del). They cover redis, python, android, cmd, gulp, vba and pretty much all other things that have a [del](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/del) command/statement/keyword.

All the top voted questions talk about the [del](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/del) keyword in python, so maybe there's a use-case there? I don't know if it's big enough to warrant a separate tag, though.

Comment: `Let's [del]ete this tag` is a better title.

Comment: Relevant: [`Should we [delete] [deletion] and [deleting]`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298476/3622940)?

Comment: @Unihedron I'm tearing up, seeing that we removed those tags.

Comment: agree to delete `del` tag, and will be nicer if `auto-delete`, `undelete` are removed also.

Comment: I love thoses burninate puns.

Comment: Hehe, I get the pun :3

Comment: Some clarifying information to guide making a decision: a) there is now a [tag info, but bizarrely it only defined 'del' as a Windows CMD/DOS file deletion command](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45691885/revisions) and didn't even mention Python, Android et al., let alone as the first meaning. I just edited it accordingly. b) Languages typically have at most zero or one `del`/`delete`/`free` command/keyword/function, they do not have both a `del` and a `delete`. So Python's `del` corresponds to C's `free()`, C++'s `delete`, Java's `obj = null` and so on. c) Now as to whether...

Comment: c) ... those similar meanings across different paradigms of manual or automatic memory management should result in tag synonyms, no tags for some languages etc., is for discussion.

Comment: d) **But in **the specific case of `del` (unlike `delete`) it happens to be near-synonymous with one language (Python), so it tags both a concept and a particular language (and thus also a particular garbage collection algorithm). So yes it obeys one of the purposes stated in the tag FAQ**: to  [*"help [Python users, anyway] identify questions that are interesting or relevant to them."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). So, `del` should not be made an alias to `delete`. (Or, we could even rename it 'python-del').

Answer (score -22):

We should keep the tag, because the more tags we have the easier we can find the right answers.

Comment: Make a tag? This question is discussing removing the tag...

Comment: According to the [help page on tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), tags should only be created if they cover a useful, well-defined topic and new ones should actually be avoided. Creating tags for the sake of increasing how many exist do not make help anything.

Comment: If having more tags would mean better searching, we would always go for fulltext.