# Should we delete [delete-file]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Related: [Should we [delete] [deletion] and [deleting]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298476/should-we-delete-deletion-and-deleting)

Just stumbled on [delete-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete-file). The excerpt says:

> Tag for questions regarding file deletion. O.S. independent.

We don't have [write-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/write-file), [create-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/create-file) or [open-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-file).

Should we delete [delete-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete-file)?

Comment: The [top users page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/delete-file/topusers) is quite amusing, as it's clear that people don't tend to see this tag more than once but have still amounted quite the reputation on some answers/questions. I don't, however, see that this tag really add anything to the questions; the problem is related to the language you are using and they all have different syntaxes for deleting a file.

Comment: Chandler voice: Can this tag - *be* - any more pointless?

Comment: As this is a burninate request, it would be useful to answer the [burnination questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/2370483)

Comment: @Machavity I’d want to discuss it first

Comment: Meh, it's not a good tag, but it has nearly 2k questions and isn't hurting anyone being around

Comment: @DanielA.White Which is the purpose of the questions. If you want a tag gone, you need to answer those four. As such, we can discuss if the tag should go and refute your reasons. Otherwise Nick's "Meh" will rule the day

Comment: Unfortunately, the burnination process is very elaborate and the current state is that we allow tags that are entirely useless, but don't fail one of the burnination criteria. This one is unambiguous and related to programming, so it meets that one -> no delete [tag:delete-file]

Comment: _“We don't have [tag:write-file], [tag:create-file] or [tag:open-file].”_ — but we do have [tag:readfile] and [tag:createfile], two Windows API functions.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this tag is suitable to be kept.

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   While [delete-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete-file) may be a bit too broad, it certainly has more [value](/q/294230) than [user](/q/268187). And yes - everyone is expecting a tagged question to be about removing files from storage locations, so I don't see much ambiguity.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Deleting files programatically is surely open for Stack Overflow.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   Yes. See point 1.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   Some would argue deleting files from a hard drive is very different from doing so on S3 or similar, but that doesn't convey ambiguity, so I'll give another Yes to this one.

Comment: So... a question about `rm`, `erase`, Recycle Bin, etc. are on topic? That's not ok.